# Why is my AngularJS code not working? It works on W3Schools editor but not on any browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "" ng-controller = "myController">
 <head>
  <title>YouToDo</title>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type = "text" maxlength = "256" width = "256" ng-model = "task"><br><br>
  <input type = "button" value = "Add" ng-click = "addTask()"><br><br>
  <table border = "0">
   <tr></tr>
  </table>
  <script>
   function myController($scope) {
       $scope.addTask = function() {
         var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tr' ) );
         myEl.prepend('<tr><td>' + $scope.task + '</td></tr>');     
       }
   }
  </script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

It works on W3Schools editor but not on any browser! Neither on Chrome nor Firefox. I have AngularJS 1.5.6. Please help.

Comment: Where have you defined your `app.module` ?

Comment: check your console

Answer (score 1):

There may be couple of issues

1. You are not correctly loading `angular` framework
2. `ng-app = ""` is  empty. It should have a name which will require to instantiate angular framework in your application
3. `angular.module('name you provided in ng-app',[])` is missing. It is also required to boot angular with you application.
4. Also take a look how write a `controller`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't run angular directly in your browser you need to have the library locally.

Please take a look at this video to help you set up your environment.
It really helped me, has also some recommended tools to handle different aspects of angular applications.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofASsumsf7E&list=PLEDbaVSIL58MB78qU6_I_FZZgNe_Mcb5j

Answer (score 0):

> Why is my AngularJS code not working?
>   Because you don't have the angular.min.js file in your lib/angular folder. But their server does.

The quick solution is to use googles hosted one.

Replace:

```
src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"
```

With

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something. Below are the things you missed.

1. Angular modulename
2. Declare angular module
3. Add controller constructor

```html
  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller = "myController">
    <head>
        <title>YouToDo</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" maxlength = "256" width = "256" ng-model = "task"><br><br>
        <input type = "button" value = "Add" ng-click = "addTask()"><br><br>
        <table border = "0">
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
        <script>
            angular.module('demoApp',[]) //call the module
                .controller('myController',myController); // controller constructor

            function myController($scope) {
                $scope.addTask = function() {
                    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tr' ) );
                    myEl.prepend('<tr><td>' + $scope.task + '</td></tr>');     
                }
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you are new to angular, so there could be a few things going wrong,

1. Your Source

   does this path really exist on your pc ?, if not i would recommend using a   CDN like
2. Try to search more on your angular code, the basic angular code would be

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("myCtrl", ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.addTask = function (){
       $scope.tasks.push({taskName : $scope.task});
      $scope.task = null;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Angular JS</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    
    <input type = "text" maxlength = "256" width = "256" ng-model = "task"><br><br>
 <input type = "button" value = "Add" ng-click = "addTask()"><br><br>
    
    <table border = "0">
   <tr ng-repeat = "x in tasks">
              <td>{{x.taskName}}</td>
            </tr>
 </table>
    
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try to use as much angular as you can, as you can see I have used ng-repeat which is a better and cleaner way to display a list.
I will also suggest that you use normal angular.js file rather than angular.min.js file because it is easier to look at errors in the un-minified version, it is just for development, at the time of release just use the minified version as it is faster to download.
Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

its not getting the angular.min.js file 
It would be better if you use CDN

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js

in script tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The first one works in W3School because they have the angularjs files at that location while you don't. either do so or change the `src` as I have shown above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">

<head>
  <title>YouToDo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" maxlength="256" width="256" ng-model="task">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addTask()">
  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="0">
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    function myController($scope) {
      $scope.addTask = function() {
        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('tr'));
        myEl.prepend('<tr><td>' + $scope.task + '</td></tr>');
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```